# How can a Black Pudding split when damaged by lightning or slashing damage if it's immune to such damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, immunities

From DND Beyond entry on Black Pudding: (bold italics are mine)

> **Damage Immunities** acid, cold, ***lightning, slashing***

At the bottom of the stat block, under Reactions, it has the ability Split:

> **Split** When a pudding that is Medium or larger ***is subjected to lightning or slashing damage***, it splits into two new puddings if it has at least 10 hit points.

If it's immune to lightning and slashing damage, how can it be 'subjected' to lightning or slashing damage in order to activate 'Split'? It's clear that 'is subjected to' means that it takes the damage. If you're immune to something you by definition cannot be 'subjected' to it.

Comment: [related question here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/121131/22566)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> It's clear that 'is subjected to' means that it takes the damage. If you're immune to something you by definition cannot be 'subjected' to it.

I think this is the crux of your misunderstanding. 'Subjected to' doesn't *have* to mean that you actually take damage such that your HP is reduced.

From the [cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/subject) (as an adjective):

> **be subject to *sth***
>   ​to have or experience a particular thing, especially something unpleasant

In this context, being 'subjected to' actually means that a certain amount of damage was dealt, and being immune, the pudding would be unaffected by it, hence its HP remains the same. However, since it was 'subjected to' that damage, even though it had no effect, it may now use it's reaction to split.

Answer (score 24):

No, that's exactly *why* it says 'when subjected to' rather than 'when damaged by' or similar language that we see in other monster blocks. They don't mean the same thing. The damage doesn't need to actually occur; the creature is "subjected to" the damage type even if they're immune, which triggers the ability. (You can see this in normal English use of the word -- "The giant robot was subjected to freezing cold, intense flames, and even a direct nuclear blast, but its armor was completely undamaged."  Clearly there is no contradiction between 'subjected to' and 'undamaged'.)

In any case, this is a situation where the intent of the monster is pretty clear, I feel, so quibbling about the language used to describe it is not all that useful.

Comment: +1 for that last paragraph, I think that's the true answer here.